# Can't I use a fractional Buy/Sell price on GnuCash that's more than 2 decimal places?

Tags: gnucash

#### Context

I want to track the transactions I made on Binance last year into GnuCash. I found out GnuCash doesn't support Bitcoin or cryptocurrencies in general, so I added them as a security, as suggested in [this Reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/GnuCash/comments/lofarf/comment/go8frjp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

As Binance uses 8 decimal places for all currencies traded on it, I created a security with symbol 'BTC' and fraction 1/100000000. Then, I created two accounts: one called "Bitcoin" for that security (BTC) and another called "Binance" for my deposits in BRL. Since BRL uses 2 decimal places by default, I changed the field 'smallest fraction' of the BRL account to match Binance's decimal places, that is, 1/100000000. So far so good.

#### Problem

When I create a transaction from "Binance" to "Bitcoin" to track a purchase of BTC, I'm allowed to input a value that's up to 8 decimals in the fields "Shares", but the fields "Buy" and "Sell" always rounds the value to 2 decimals places.

To demonstrate it with actual data, my first purchase was on 11 May 2021. I bought 0.000117 BTC when BTC/BRL was at 297,782, which resulted in an expense of precisely 34.840494 BRL. That's the amount I want to place in the field "Buy" of the ledger of the account "Bitcoin", but as soon as I finish editing the field, GnuCash rounds it to 34.84 BRL and automatically adjusts the field "Price" to 297,777.7778, which is incorrect. I spent 34.840494 BRL, not 34.84 BRL.

I thought this might be due to the fact that the account "Binance" uses a 2-digit fiat currency (BRL); that GnuCash might be disregarding my setting for 'smallest fraction', so I had the idea of creating a security for BRL that has 8 decimal places. That didn't work either. I'm afraid GnuCash has hardcoded a 2-digit rounding strategy for values in the fields "Buy" and "Sell". Is there any workaround for this or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm confused. It looks like BRL can only be split to 0.01 ([source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_real)). Why do you need to track further fractions?

Comment: @glibdud It seems it's a problem with all currencies, no matter which one you choose. I tried to replace BRL with USD but the problem remains. As for your question, I want to track all fractions for the sake of accuracy, since those are the actual values I traded on Binance. Moreover, I made many transactions; I'm afraid if I input all of them, the rounding will result in an incorrect balance in the end.

Comment: It's weird that GnuCash doesn't allow it, though, since it allows you to choose an account's "smallest fraction". It's as though GnuCash said, "You can select more than 2 digits for an account, but it's all for the sake of showing more zeroes."

Comment: Did Binance actually charge you 34.840494 BRL for the purchase? How did you pay the 0.000494?

Comment: @glibdud Yup. All transactions I made on Binance have more than 2 decimal places. I payed the 0.000494 with my account balance. On Binance, your currencies are ALWAYS using 8 decimal places, so, for instance, when I made a deposit of 350 BRL from my bank account, it arrived at Binance as 350.00000000. I reckon Binance made it this way so that all currencies can match Bitcoin's decimal places. So, when I made my first transaction, I ended up with a BRL balance of (350.00000000 - 34.840494) = 315.159506.

Answer (score 1):

Since your broker is allowing you (forcing you?) to trade in small fractions of a BRL, one workaround is to create a security in GnuCash that is worth... a small fraction of a BRL.

I created a security (working title: "**miniBRL**") which can be exchanged at the rate of 10,000 miniBRL = 1.00 BRL.  (*I also trialled the microBRL, worth one millionth of a BRL, but GnuCash would not accept the astronomical exchange rate for purchasing BTC with microBRL.  **miniBRL** worked though, on your example trade.*)

So now, when you actually bought 0.000117 BTC with 34.840494 BRL, your GnuCash process could be:

1. Convert (buy) 350,000.00 miniBRL using 35.00 BRL from your Binance trading account.
2. Use 348,404.94 miniBRL to purchase 0.000117 BTC at an exchange rate of 2,977,820,000

After this process, the GnuCash accounts for BRL and miniBRL in your trading account should align with Binance's records of BRL in your trading account.

Comment: Interesting approach. Haven't thought of creating a mini fiat currency for intermediary transactions. It's kinda cumbersome having to create mini currencies (and thus, two GnuCash accounts) for all currencies I traded (ETH, BNB, BUSD, ADA, etc.), but it seems this is the only way.

Also, you said "in your trading account" in the last paragraph. What do you mean?

Comment: I tried using your solution, and it works at transaction level, but there is a problem with the resulting balance in the account book. Namely, the step 2 (0.000117 BTC at 2,977,820,000) causes the Buy price to go to 348,404.94, and although that's correct in the ledger, when I look at my account tree, I see a huge balance on the BTC account, which is incorrect.

Comment: Kinda cumbersome, agreed.  But at its heart, I think that GnuCash is an accounting system, not a system designed from the ground up to handle currency trades or stock accounts.  Those are add-ons with limited functionality.  By "trading account", I meant the money that you've paid to Binance which hasn't yet been spent on buying cryptocurrency.  It's analogous to the money that you've put into your cheque account at your bank, so that a cheque (when you write it in future) will have funds available to cover it.  You might use different terminology.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to by "a huge balance on the BTC account".  I didn't see that in my test,

Comment: You probably won't need to create separate mini currencies for all crypto currencies that you trade.  By which I mean that miniBRL (and/or BRL) might be around the right size for purchases of several other currencies besides BTC.

Comment: By "huge balance on the BTC account", I meant a huge balance not of BTC, but rather of BRL. When GnuCash calculates the amount of BRL that 0.000117 BTC is worth, it will result in a huge value of BRL, which is shown on parents accounts. For example, I have an account "Cryptocurrency" (denominated in BRL) under which I have the account "Bitcoin". On the account tree, "Bitcoin" will show a balance of 0.000117 BTC, but "Cryptocurrency" will show a much higher amount of BRL than it should, something like 100x what it should be.

Comment: I said "huge balance on the BTC account" because I had enabled a column that shows a BRL balance for all accounts in the account tree, so it shows both the BTC and the BRL balances of the "Bitcoin" account side by side. I now realize the way I phrased it sounded like it was a huge balance of BTC, sorry lol

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  In my test file, it looks like the valuation of the "Binance Brokerage Fund" is made up of the value of the bitcoins *expressed in miniBRL* for some reason, + the number of unspent BRL, and *ignoring* the unspent miniBRL.  I'm really not sure why those figures were added up in that way, and the result is obviously meaningless - it's nothing like the true value of your holdings through Binance.  That's just weird!  But hopefully you will get sensible figures if you look at the individual accounts and ignore the supposed total for the Binance funds.

Comment: Yeah. As I have the "Bitcoin" account under a top-level "Asset" account, it affects the whole balance. When I look at the balance of "Asset", it shows a huge amount of BRL, which I only wish I have lol Anyway, it seems this thing can't be done cleanly on GnuCash, so I'll try adding my transactions with a wrong "Buy" price (such as 297,777.7778 rather than 297,782 BTC) and leave a comment on the transaction's description indicating the correct buy/sell price. If that still doesn't work, I guess there's no cryptocurrency tracking on GnuCash... But thanks for you help, bro.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my answer to [this other question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152962/), the number of decimals allowed in the Buy and Sell columns is tied to the base currency of your GnuCash file. I found this out via trial and error. For example, if you select XPT (Platina) as your base currency, which has a precision of 1/1000000, then you are allowed to enter more decimals.

Of course, using XPT is not a solution, but this is how GnuCash works currently (V 4.12). On bugs.gnucash.org you can find several tickets related to bitcoin support but they are still in progress (some of them for several years).

A solution would be to change the name and precision of a currency in the factory list to Bitcoin, but currently it is not allowed. I read somewhere that the list is fixed and comes from some ISO standard. It can include only accepted currencies of countries and some extras like Gold and Platina.